# Updating lists shared from multiple threads int Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to create a program where a list of integers is sorted using multiple threads that can all read it and write onto specific parts of it during multiple steps. Each thread is an instance of the same object and works with an other thread on the same part of the list. My problem is that each thread can't see the changes made to the list by the other thread so some of the initial elements of the list are lost on the way. Is there a way to refresh or maybe update the list, so that the thread will be able to have the changed list?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to make sure that all the threads are accessing the same List, make it static or shared variable.
2. How about using a Vector instead of List , Vector is thread safe

If multiple threads access an ArrayList concurrently then we must externally synchronize the block of code which modifies the list either structurally or simply modifies an element. Structural modification means addition or deletion of element(s) from the list. Setting the value of an existing element is not a structural modification.

Collections.synchronizedList is normally used at the time of creation of the list to avoid any accidental unsynchronized access to the list.

[Link to reference](http://geekexplains.blogspot.com/2008/05/difference-between-vector-and-arraylist.html)

Comment: I'm using an array and not ArrayList. I tried making the list static but it doesn't change anything and a Vector doesn't have the methods I want to use. Is there something more I should do for the list to work or a specific example?

Comment: @orestrag97 in your question you state clearly that you're using _"a list of integers"_ and now you say _"I'm using an array and not ArrayList."_ - So what is it? Array or List? And please update your question accordingly to make that clear.

Answer (score -1):

What about just using Java8 [parallel Streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html)?

```
List<Integer> sortedList = theList.parallelStream()
                                  .sorted()
                                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```